# Limpiar datos de un textbox - System.FormatException

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el evento textBox1_TextChanged

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out velocidad_inicial))
        {
            velocidad_inicial = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Y tengo otro evento button2_Click

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Text");
    }
```

Cuando intento borrar los datos a través de este ultimo me arroja el siguiente error en el textBox_1.
System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'
Como podría solucionarlo?? Mis demás textBox están implementados de manera similar, por lo que posiblemente me lance los mismos errores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma como estás usando el [`Decimal.TryParse(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) no es la adecuada.

La idea del patrón `.TryParse()` es proveer un mecanismo de conversión que no produce Excepciones.

- Cuando la conversión es exitosa, su resultado es `true` y asigna el valor convertido al parámetro de salida (`velocidad_inicial` en tu caso).
- Cuando la conversión falla, su resultado es `false` y el parámetro de salida es cero.

En tu código estás tratando de hacer otra conversión con `Convert.ToDecimal` cuando se sabe que no es posible porque `Decimal.TryParse` falló.

Al limpiar los datos del `textBox1` se produce el evento `textBox1_TextChanged` en ese momento `TryParse` resulta `false` y `Convert.ToDecimal` produce la excepción que mencionas en tu pregunta.

Para resolverlo debes cambiar el manejador de evento `textBox1_TextChanged` utilizando la guía que te dejo a continuación:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  |  Aquí quita la negación
    //  V
    if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out velocidad_inicial))
    {

        //En este punto el resultado de la conversión lo tienes en 
        //velocidad_inicial y no es necesario una nueva conversión.

    }
    else
    {

        // En este punto la conversión no es posible.
        // Lo menciono solo como una referencia pero puedes omitirlo.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No tiene sentido lo que esta haciendo. Usted esta validando que el dato en textbox1 **NO** sea un decimal para luego convertirlo a decimal??????  Claramente por eso le da el formatException.

Si usted quiere que el dato en el textbox sea decimal entonces debería ser así:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out velocidad_inicial))
        {
            velocidad_inicial = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Quitarle la negación, osea el !